# Making join with SQL Server table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sql-server

I'd like to join .shp to table by using [AddJoin_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000) but I'd like to make join to an SQL Server table (not to *.dbf).

Is it possible to do?

It should look something like this:

```
AddJoin_management ("my_layer.shp", "ID", SQL-SERVER-TABLE, "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be straightforward.

Add your shapefile and SQL Server table to ArcMap 10.0 or later.

Open, fill in the fields, and run the **Add Join** tool interactively.

Now go to **Geoprocessing | Results** and use **Copy As Python Snippet** on the tool to get the correct syntax in your Python script.

You may also need to use **Make Feature Layer** and **Make Table View** to make the shapefile and table accessible to Add Join.